# How do I make an increaser for several variables?

Tags: scala

I have a class with several variables containing Integers and I want a method which increases one of them by a certain amount depending on the call.

```
case class Bank {
  private var depo = 0
  private var loan = 0


  def deposit(amount: Int): Boolean = {
      if(amount>0) {
        depo += amount
        true
        } else false
  }

  def withdraw(amount: Int): Boolean = {
      if(amount > 0 && amount <= balance) {
        depo -= amount
        true
        } else false
  }

  def balance_=(b:Int) = {
    if(b >= 0) {
        if(b < depo) withdraw(depo-b) else deposit(b-depo)
    } else false
  }

  def balance = depo
}
```

When I want to increase deposits, I just call

```
myBank.balance += 10
```

but when I now want to increase loan, I have to write an additional method, right?
Is there a possibility to write a method like

```
increaser(varToIncrease, amount)
```

Is that possible or even useful? Or do I have to write an "increaser"-method for every single var?

Comment: I agree with @om-nom-nom. Why have a function to perform the addition unless additional things are happening in this function (like side effects which should probably be avoided anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm kind of new to Scala. My problem is that when I want to increase var x by 100, I do that with x.increase(100) but when I want to increase var y I have to write a second method for y. That doesn't make sense to me, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you post some more code showing this issue in detail. That way you can get the best possible suggestions for solutions.

Comment: Why would you allow someone from outside of the `Bank` class to add money to the `depo` var without going through the `deposit` function. This breaks encapsulation.

Comment: I want to model the balance sheet of banks with several entries, so I have to write a method like the `deposit` for every entry in order to increase it?

Comment: Generally, yes, but I'm not going to say you 100% of the time have to do that.  Will there be conditional logic tied to the mutation of that internal var?  If so then yes, you should have a separate function to handle a request to mutate that variable.  If the mutation logic is the same conditions for both `depo` and `load`, then you can certainly add a private generalized function to bank to perform those checks and then have the public functions just delegate to this general function to avoid boilerplate logic.

Comment: Ok, great. The conditional logic would be the same for a bunch of balance sheet entries. That's why I'm looking for an appropriate implementation of such a private generalized function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for based on your additional comments:

```
case class Bank {
  private var depo = 0
  private var loans = 0


  def deposit(amount: Int): Boolean = addTo(amount, depo += amount)

  def loan(amount: Int): Boolean = addTo(amount, loans += amount)

  private def addTo(amount:Int, func: => Unit):Boolean = {
    if(amount > 0) {
      func
      true
    } 
    else 
      false    
  }



  def withdraw(amount: Int): Boolean = {
      if(amount > 0 && amount <= balance) {
        depo -= amount
        true
        } else false
  }

  def balance_=(b:Int) = {
    if(b >= 0) {
        if(b < depo) withdraw(depo-b) else deposit(b-depo)
    } else false
  }

  def balance = depo
  def loanAmount = loans
}

object BankTest{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val b = new Bank
    println("Starting amounts, " + b.balance + ", " + b.loanAmount)

    b.deposit(10)
    println(b.balance)
    b.deposit(-1)
    println(b.balance)

    b.loan(100)
    println(b.loanAmount)
    b.loan(-50)
    println(b.loanAmount)  
  }

}
```

I created two public functions to increase balance and loaned amount respectively.  Then, I created an interval `addTo` function to handle the business logic of performing an operation to increase one of those vars.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase the integer parameter inside another method. If you want to create an increaser method as you wanted, you have to pass in an immutable object into the method.